# MySQL changing database collation

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Hello is there a general way to change database collation in MySQL for everything in one go, I mean for triggers, procedures, tables and etc. ?

Comment: Does executing a series alter commands in a script count as one go? If yes, then you can do it. If not, then not. There is no single command to achieve what you are after.

Comment: You can do whole dump, replace collation in file and load dump

Answer (score 0):

Dump, lots of edits to the dump file, then reload.  This should work, but it is risky in that you might miss something.

Do you mean `CHARACTER SET` (as `latin1` versus `utf8`)?  Or do you mean `COLLATION` (as in `utf8mb4_general_ci` versus `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`)?

Tables need `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...`.  You can write a simple `SELECT` against `information_schema` to generate all the table `ALTERs`.  Triggers and Routines may need to be recreated, since they take on the setting in effect when they are created.